# SQL FOR XML Help

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql, for-xml

Prob an easy question, but I am new to forming XML in SQL 2005, but What would be the best FOR XML SQL statement to use to form the XML seen below from a table that looks like this?

```
Column1     Column2   
------------------------
Baseball    Football   
Cricket     Polo       
Swim        Beach
```

Desired XML output:

```
<Category Name="Baseball">
  <Subcategory>Football</Subcategory>
</Category>
<Category Name="Cricket">
  <SubCategory>Polo</Subcategory>
</Category>
<Category Name="Swim">
  <SubCategory>Beach</Subcategory>
</Category>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested:

```
SELECT t.column1 AS "@Name",
       t.column2 AS Subcategory
  FROM TABLE t
FOR XML PATH ('Category')
```

Based [on examples found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510462.aspx).

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the link and example!